# How do I filter date in react component

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using the Django rest framework to create API and it is returning `2022-03-04T05:16:07.552250Z` this data how do I filter only date from this data.

Comment: `date.slice(0,10)`?

Answer (score 0):

Use Moment.js to format the date in React

```
npm install moment
```

In your React component:

```js
const date = // fetched date

var moment = require('moment');

const formattedDate = moment(date).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
```

You can see other ways to format [here](https://momentjs.com/)